# Using operator new and placement new to create a dynamic array of non-default constructible objects

Tags: c++, new-operator, placement-new

I am new to `placement new` so I wanted to separate allocation from initialization using it along `operator new` to allocate and construct an array of my user-defined type `class Foo`.

here is what I've tried:

```
struct Foo{
    Foo(int x) : x_(x){
        std::cout << "Foo(int)\n";
    }
    ~Foo(){
        std::cout << "~Foo()\n";
    }
    int x_ = 0;
};

int main(){

    Foo* pf = static_cast<Foo*>(operator new[](10 * sizeof(Foo) ) );

    for(int i  = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        new(pf + i)Foo(i * 7);

    for(int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        std::cout << pf[i].x_ << ", ";
    std::cout << '\n';

    for(int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        pf[i].~Foo();

    operator delete[](pf);

}
```

- The code looks to work fine so please guide me if I've missed something. And is this similar to how `class allocator` works? (separate allocation from initialization).

Comment: This looks mostly fine to me, but this wouldn't respect the alignment requirements of Foo if Foo were over-aligned. I would change it to `Foo* pf = static_cast<Foo*>(operator new[](10 * sizeof(Foo), std::align_val_t{alignof(Foo)} ) );` if Foo were a template type.

Comment: I would get rid of `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]` altogether, and use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) for the array, eg: `using elemType = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Foo), alignof(Foo)>; elemType data* = new elemType[10]; Foo* pf = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(data); ... for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { new (pf+i) Foo(...); } ... for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) pf[i].~Foo(); ... delete[] data;`

Comment: You could use `std::vector` as you can `emplace` data into it. Much simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `elemType *data = ...` (typo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> please guide me if I've missed something.

Seems fine for `Foo`. But more generally, the approach isn't exception safe. If one of the class constructors throw, then your allocation leaks and the previously constructed objects won't be destroyed.

> And is this similar to how class allocator works?

Quite similar. A few differences:

- `std::allocator<T>::allocate` uses `::operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)` and `std::allocator<T>::deallocate` calls `::operator delete(void*, std::align_val_t)` since C+++17. This is needed to support over-aligned types.
- Technically, you never start lifetime of an array. This isn't a big problem in practice. There isn't any practical way to create dynamic arrays in reused memory. Although, since C++20
  `std::allocator<T>::allocate` actually does start the lifetime of an array of `T` (without starting the lifetime of the objects). There's technically no way to implement that in standard C++ for non-trivial types.

Comment: If using `std::allocator<T>::allocate` is there a way to call [std::allocator<T>::deallocate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/deallocate) with `pf` instead of `data` or are you limited to calling `.deallocaate()` on `data`, the actual pointer obtained with `.allocate()`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm confused about what you mean by `data`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was looking at this on [godbolt source](https://godbolt.org/z/cY7hPhsva) where the define `ALLOCA` triggers the use of `std::allocator`. (this probably should be a separate question -- I'll delete the comments in a bit, but am curious if I was looking at it right)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, using an allocator is entirely separate from using `std::aligned_storage`. You pass the result of `operator ::new` to `operator ::delete` and you pass the result of `std::allocator::allocate` to `std::allocator::deallocate`, just like you pass result of `new` to `delete` or `delete[]`.

Comment: Thank you -- that is where I was getting hung up.